# "not authorized on admin to execute command" even using root role

Tags: mongodb, admin, root

I'm trying to execute the following 'query' on the primary node of my mongodb cluster:

```
> db.system.sessions.count()
```

The cluster gives me an error as follow:

> "not authorized on admin to execute command", "unauthorized"

The [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-root) said that the role 'root' has implicitly the 'clusterAdmin' role, what I suppose is enough to query the sessions count.

This is the user/roles I'm logged in:

```
{
    "user" : "admshard",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterManager",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

My mongodb version is 4.2.3. I'm working with 2 databases and 2 arbiters.

Any clue about this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Obviously, I'm not authorized to any query on db.system :(

Comment: The `system.sessions` collection is in `config` database.

Comment: Strange, role `{ role : "root", db: "admin"} ` should permit almost everything. Did you connect with correct password?

Comment: Got it. So I'm trying to run against config db the [$listSessions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/listSessions/) but it requires privileges with listSessions [action](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#mongodb-authaction-listSessions) and I have no idea on how I grant it to the logged in user!

Comment: Also, I found someone that was trying to access the `system.sessions` collection and he/she had to give access (grant a role) to the collection [specifically](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37624?focusedCommentId=2040343&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2040343). I tried the same, but no results.

Comment: Verify you are authenticated.

Comment: @D.SM Yes mate, I am authenticated!!

Comment: Not related to your question, but why do you have 2 arbiters?

Comment: What do you get from `db.runCommand({connectionStatus : 1, showPrivilege: true})`?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit both on the config and admin database shows me the "authenticatedUsers" (me) and the roles ("authenticatedUserRoles")

Answer (score 2):

The [root](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-root) role provide the privileges granted by the roles:

- readWriteAnyDatabase
- dbAdminAnyDatabase
- userAdminAnyDatabase
- clusterAdmin
- restore
- backup

[clusterManager](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-clusterManager) grants the find privilege on All ***non-system*** collections in the config database

[readWriteAnyDatabase](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#mongodb-authrole-readWriteAnyDatabase) grants  the same privileges as readWrite on all databases except local and config, and also provides the listDatabases action on the cluster as a whole.

You may need to create a custom role, and use [grantPivildgesToRole](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantPrivilegesToRole/) to give it the find action on the config.system.sessions collection.

Comment: Almost there! I created a role on the config database, granting the action 'listSessions' to the cluster resource, as the docs said [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/createRole/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#mongodb-authaction-listSessions). So now, when I get the roles from the db (`show roles`), the role was create on the `admin` database, not on the `config` db! I repeat, I followed the instructions, which said "The role applies to the database on which you run the command"

Comment: The commands, were:
```
use config
db.adminCommand(
    {createRole: "<therolename>",
        privileges: [
            { resource: { cluster: true }, 
                actions: [ "listSessions" ] 
            }
        ],
    roles: [
        { role: "dbOwner", db: "config" }
    ]
})
```

Comment: the listSessions privilege grants permission to use [$listSessions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/listSessions/).  If you wan to run `count` directly on the sessions collection, I think you will need find privilege

Comment: for sure. no doubts about it. did you read my last commentary?

Comment: Yes, but also not that the dbOwner role provide read-write privilege for all _non-system_ collections, so that still won't let you directly query the system.sessions collection.  For system collections, you will need to create an action for that collection.

Comment: I probably should have asked this earlier - what exactly are you trying to do?  If you want the total number of active sessions, use the `$listSessions` aggregation stage.  The real list of sessions is cached in memory, and only periodically persisted to the config.system.sessions collection, so querying that collection directly will likely give you stale data.

Comment: Joe, first: thanks for your time and responses. second: when I opened the question I was trying to query the system.sessions directly but now I am using the $listSessions to get the sessions. The problem is, even I granting the right action (listSessions) to the right resource (cluster) on the right db (config), I'm not allowed to execute the query, unfortunately. I'm using palliatively the [$listLocalSessions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/listLocalSessions/) operation. It is fine for now :D